# How to take entry based on time range

Tags: pine-script

Let say I have a condition for long and short entry but I want to enter only if the condition gets satisfied between market open and half an hour after that and no entry after specified time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a time input for that, then have a variable to check if the current bar is in that time window. Simply `and` that variable with your condition.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
timeAllowed = input.session(defval="1200-1300", title="Allowed hours")

isWithinTime = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":1234567")
my_rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
rsi_50 = my_rsi > 50
plotshape(series=rsi_50, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.red, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(series=rsi_50 and isWithinTime, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.green, size=size.small, location=location.abovebar)
```

Please check the below screenshot. Red triangles are where `rsi > 50`, and the green triangles are where `rsi > 50` `AND` if the time is between 12:00 and 13:00

[image]